# How to configure timeout for nodejs on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, timeout

How to configure timeout for nodejs on Heroku. Heroku timesout at 30seconds. I would like to timeout at 25th second. How do we configure ?

Answer (score -1):

At this moment there is a method to do this directly on the request object:

```
request.setTimeout(timeout, [callback]);
```

This is a shortcut method that binds to the socket event and then creates the timeout.

Reference: [Node.js Timers Manual & Documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html)